# openSessionWithAllowLoginUI almost always returns NO

Tags: ios, facebook

I've recently finished integrating the latest FB iOS SDK (3.0) into my app (iOS 5). I've stepped through the tutorials, and everything appears to be in place according to the FB provided docs. The issue I'm having is that whenever I check to see if I need to authenticate via:

if(![self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO])
{
    [self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
}

... often (and almost always after [FBSession.activeSession close]) openSessionWithAllowLoginUI returns NO, and I have to transition to the authentication dialog to get a valid session. According to my understanding, [FBSession.activeSession close] should not disrupt the ability of the SDK to re-use old tokens and allow me to recreate a session without having to display the login dialog.

Note that in my app, I don't require Facebook authentication for the duration of the app lifetime. Therefore, I tend to establish sessions on demand, and tear them down with [FBSession.activeSession close] exactly when I'm done, as opposed to only having [FBSession.activeSession close] in applicationWillTerminate.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong or things to try?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and I can't figure out...
The selector openSessionWithAllowLoginUI: is not able to retrieve saved session for the user and always I have to show the login UI to user.

I hope to solve it asap!

UPDATE -------------

Something I understood: when a user log-into Facebook, the FB SDK makes 2 calls to sessionStateChanged:

The first is for a FBSessionStateOpen and the second for FBSessionStateClosed. So, if you check your AppDelegate.m file you'll find a code like this:

```
case FBSessionStateClosed:
case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
     [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
     break;
```

The call to closeAndClearTokenInformation: clear all token information so every time the App is run, it will ask the login UI to the user.

Now the question is: WHY Facebook first send FBSessionStateOpen and immediately FBSessionStateClosed ??

Comment: I'm also getting this behaviour in 3.1.1 - I've removed: [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]; from case FBSessionStateClosed: because this would always invalidate my token

Answer (score 1):

I could never get openSessionWithAllowLoginUI to work properly. Instead, use this:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"user_relationships"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    switch (status) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            [self start];
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
            break;
        case FBSessionStateCreated:
            break;
        case FBSessionStateCreatedOpening:
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            break;
        case FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended:
            break;
        case FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded:
            break;
    }

}];
```

Add a [self start] method and modify the permissions array to suit your needs. This works consistently.

Comment: What does - (void)start do ?