# Facebook ios6 completionHandler not called after signing in

Tags: xcode, facebook, ios6, ios-frameworks

I am trying to publish on Facebook using **openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions**  , so if the user is not logged in he need's to first sign in and then post the message using io6 Facebook native Dialog.

What I found is I am able to login, but completion handler is not called.

Another thing I noticed, that when I click the login button again, it then calls completion handler with the following error ***FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed***.

I did refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514740/facebook-sdk-openactivesessionwithpermissions-completionhandler-not-called) but still did not find a solution to my problem.

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil];
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:
^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) 
{

  switch (status) {

                  case FBSessionStateOpen:
                        {
                          [FBNativeDialogs presentShareDialogModallyFrom:currentController initialText:nil image:nil url:nil handler:^(FBNativeDialogResult result, NSError *error) {}];
                        }
                        break;   
                   default:
                        break;
                    }
                }];
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you implemented the `handleOpenUrl` method.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
           openURL:(NSURL *)url 
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
        annotation:(id)annotation {

     return [[FBSession activeSession] handleOpenURL:url]; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to add this:

```
[FBNativeDialogs presentShareDialogModallyFrom:currentController initialText:nil
  image:nil url:nil handler:^(FBNativeDialogResult result, NSError *error) {
  if (result==FBNativeDialogResultCancelled) {
    UIAlertView     *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"
       message:@"Sending Cancelled" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
       otherButtonTitles: nil];
   [alert show];
 } else if (result==FBNativeDialogResultSucceeded) {
   UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Succeed" 
     message:@"succeed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
     otherButtonTitles: nil];
  [alert show];
}***}***];
```