# Facebook iOS SDK 3.1 openActiveSession.. always returns 0

Tags: ios5, facebook-ios-sdk

I am working on an application that needs to be able to upload an image for the app for iOS versions 5.0+. For iOS 6, I have easily implemented the social feed that works perfectly.

For iOS 5, I am using the Facebook iOS SDK version 3.1. I use the methods that were in the tutorials, and so when I got to publish the image on iOS <6.0, I call the following method:

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
{
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions", nil] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        [self sessionStateChanged:session
                            state:status
                            error:error];
    }];
}
```

With `[self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];` I always get back NO (0) and  sessionStateChanged:state:error is never called due to it returning 0.

I have the app set up correctly, the two different parts set up in the plist, etc. etc., but for some reason this code on my iOS 5.0 device does not want to return correctly. (Just like in [openSessionWithAllowLoginUI almost always returns NO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115909/opensessionwithallowloginui-almost-always-returns-no?lq=1))

Does anyone have any solutions on why it would always be returning no? I have the official FB app installed on the device, I am logged into my account...I am not getting any errors or anything...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am also having the same issue while adding FB integration to my latest iOS App. I have used same code few weeks earlier on my another app and it is STILL building fine. However this one showing " openSessionWithAllowLoginUI almost always returns NO".

I guess it is due to change in settings in FB App. It says it will take some time to propagate all changes. Hoping this is issue. If any guys have any idea do let us know! Thanks!